# Yii2 console migration down with a different connection fails

Tags: yii2

Am trying to perform console migrations to a different connecton but down fails

in my connection i have

```
  'db' => [
        'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',
        'dsn' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=pos_db',
          ....other configs
    ],
    'connection_identifier' => [
        'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',
        'dsn' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=newdbo',
        ...other configs
    ],
```

In my console i have

```
public function init()
{
    $this->db = 'connection_identifier';
    parent::init();
}

public function safeUp()
{
    $this->createTable('database_connection_domains', [
        'id' => $this->primaryKey(),
        'domain'=>$this->text()->notNull(),
        'connection_id'=>$this->integer()->notNull(),
        'created_at' => $this->integer()->notNull(),
        'status'=>$this->integer()->defaultValue(0),
        'FOREIGN KEY (connection_id) REFERENCES database_connections (id) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE CASCADE',
    ]);


}

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function safeDown()
{
    $this->dropTable('database_connection_domains');
}
```

When i run the up migration the database in correctly created on the `newdbo` database. The problem comes in during down command where the table is not dropped. How do i make this drop the table.

When i run `/yii migrate/fresh` am getting an error `Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'database_connections' already exists` which means that the table is not dropped
What am i missing?

Comment: I guess you need to drop the foreign key first? Do you get any errors?

Comment: Am getting an erro Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'database_connections' already exists. Which means that its the table not getting dropped when i run ./yii migrate/fresh after all tables have been dropped and been readded

Comment: What does it say when you run `php yii migrate/down all`?

Comment: It shows success   with a message Migrated down successfully.

Comment: Thanks . when i run yii migrate/down all it now drops all tables  even in other database and i can reapply then with yii migrate. Why does this fail during yii migrate/fresh

Comment: Not sure. `fresh` truncates the database, while down just reverts the migrations. Maybe your user does not have the permissions to truncate?

Answer (score 1):

`./yii migrate/fresh` does not use migrations to cleanup database, is uses [custom implementation](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/bf73b9e80fd2aa023cccc1255b53db6ce867188b/framework/console/controllers/MigrateController.php#L296-L325) which just deletes all tables in correct order. So your settings for DB component are never used. You need to configure database on command call:

```
./yii migrate/fresh --db=connection_identifier
```

Comment: but it uses the `$this->db` which has the definition **the DB connection object or the application component ID of the DB connection to use when applying migrations** or am I getting it wrong?

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam I don't really get your point. Migrations are not used to cleanup database by `migrate/fresh` so every setting inside of migration will be ignored.

Comment: I was talking about the first 2 lines in the `truncateDatabase()` function in the custom implementation link you have added in your answer.

Comment: `truncateDatabase()` is implemented at `MigrateController` level, OP is trying to configure DB component at `Migration` level. These are two separate classes.